# How to change this iterative fn to a recursive one in python

Tags: python, recursion

```
def g(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        h(i)
```

h refers to an outer function that you are calling. How could you turn this function into a recursive function in python?

Answer (score 1):

```
def g(n):
    if not n: 
        return
    g(n-1)
    h(n-1)
```